# Need help fixing z-index issue with hover effect over image that has overaly elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need some help troubleshooting and fixing a problem I'm having on a WordPress site that I'm developing, which involves a commercial theme that I've been heavily modifying.  Here is the specific page URL that I'll be referring to:

https://dev.royalpalm.com/waterfront-listings/

The problem that I'm having is that .. when hovering over the images for any of the 3  realestate listings that are on this page, you'll notice that bottom overlay that displays the address and price "grows" to reveal a bit more info (ie: beds, baths, square footage .. and a company logo).  However, although you can reliably trigger this effect by hovering over either the image or the blank areas of the semi-transparent overlay -- the whole thing falls apart if you then move your mouse pointer and hover over any of the other overlaid elements, ... namely the gold-colored status label in the upper right hand corner, the address, the price, beds, baths, square footage, and the company logo.  You'll see that when doing so, the overlay then "shrinks", effectively ruining the effect.  What I'm trying to do is have it so that when you hover over ANY of those additional overlaid elements, .. the desired hover effect should remain in tact.

Note that I am overriding some of the parent theme's CSS to some extent, but here is the code that I've been refining and struggling with, and that I'm hoping I can repair. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

-- Yvan

```
/* WATERFRONT PROPERTIES */

body:not(.home) .hover-effect::before {
    position:absolute;  
    top:auto;   
    bottom:0;
    background-image:none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height:60px;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

body:not(.home) .hover-effect:hover::before {
    height:120px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

/* 
body:not(.home) .item-wrap.item-wrap-v3.h-100 h2.item-title:hover ~ .hover-effect::before {
    height:120px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
} 
*/

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3 h2 {
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    font-size:24px;
    letter-spacing:1.5px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    bottom:15px!important;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3:hover h2 {
    bottom:70px!important;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    cursor:pointer;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3 h2 a:hover, 
.item-wrap-v3 h2 a:active {
    color:#fff;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3 .item-price-wrap {
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    left:auto!important;
    right:20px!important;
    bottom:20px!important;  
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3 .item-price-wrap .item-price {
    font-size:18px;
    font-style:italic;  
    font-weight:300!important;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3:hover .item-price-wrap {
    bottom:75px!important;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    cursor:pointer;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3 .item-amenities.item-amenities-with-icons {
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3:hover .item-amenities.item-amenities-with-icons {
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3 .rpp-crest {
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    width:55px;
    bottom:15px;
    right:20px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;   
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3:hover .rpp-crest {
    opacity:1;  
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3 li.h-beds, 
.item-wrap-v3 li.h-baths {
    border-right:1px solid #ddd;
    font-size:18px; 
    line-height:18px; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:0 15px 0 0;
}

body:not(.home) .item-wrap-v3 li.h-area {
    font-size:18px; 
    line-height:18px; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone here provide any insight or assistance with this issue?  It's been a couple of weeks now and I'm still spinning my wheels with this one.  I'm kind of new to this whole stack exchange thing, but I remember someone recently putting a "bounty" on one of my previous questions which seemed to stir up some activity. But I'm not quite sure how to do that .. or if I'm even eligible to.  At the very least, .. could someone here perhaps provide some clarification for me regarding all of that and how it works?

Comment: Ok .. so I guess I don't even have enough reputation points to even be able to put a bounty on this question, so I guess so much for that.  Still .. can anyone here offer any assistance?  And is there any additional information that I could provide that might give some more clarity? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well .. after much experimenting, I came across this little CSS property which solved all of my troubles.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

I simply specified this property for each element that's overlaying my large thumbnails (ie: h2, ul, div, a, img) and I am now getting the desired effect.  Hopefully this finding will spare someone else the hassle some day.

https://dev.royalpalm.com/waterfront-listings/